# What should the Soundcloud redirect_uri be if I am running my grunt local server?

Tags: angularjs, uri, soundcloud, gruntjs, yeoman

I am just getting started with Soundcloud API and I got snagged on authentication. I have built my AngularJS project with Yeoman and use `grunt server` to preview my project in the browser at

`http://localhost:9000/#/`

That is the URL for the `index.html` which is the main page of my AngularJS app. I have added the following `callback.html` file ([found here at Soundcloud API docs](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
  </head>
  <body onload="window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
    <b style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b>
  </body>
</html>
```

in my project's `app` directory which is where the `index.html` file is located. Additionally and in irrational desperation, I have configured my AngularJS app to serve the `callback.html` file as a view at the URL

`http://localhost:9000/#/callback`

I thought maybe it would find it that way. I am starting to think the `redirect_uri` has to be hosted on an actual server. I am not sure if the grunt's server qualifies as a server that can serve files anywhere but locally.

**Any ideas on what my** `redirect_uri` **would look like knowing that my** `callback.html` **file is located in the** `app` **directory of my AngularJS app?**

### UPDATE 1

I have tried different URL/URI combinations.

**Combo 1**

in my Javascript:

```
redirect_uri: "http://localhost:9000/#/callback"
```

in my app settings

```
http://localhost:9000/#/callback.html
```

**Combo 2**

in my Javascript:

```
redirect_uri: "http://localhost:9000/#/callback.html"
```

in my app settings

```
http://localhost:9000/#/callback.html
```

**Combo 3**

in my Javascript:

```
redirect_uri: "http://localhost:9000/#/callback.html"
```

in my app settings

```
http://localhost:9000/#/callback
```

Additionally when I run this in Chrome I see this error show up in the console in Chrome Dev Tools:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier           useranalyzr.js:4
```

As you can see in my `useranalyzr.js` file the 4th line is the `redirect_uri`.

```
window.onload = function() {
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: '###################################'
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:9000/#/callback.html"
  });

  SC.connect(function(){
    SC.put("/me/followings/12345", function(user, error) {
      if(error){
        alert("Error: " + error.message);
      }else{
        alert("You are now following " + user.username);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

So yeah, no matter what combination I try I always get the same error. I am starting to think that I need to just find a way to get grunt to serve the static callback.html file with out the AngularJS routes getting in the way. Just the direct link.

### UPDATE 2

Ok I am able to serve up `callback.html` at `http://localhost:9000/callback.html` and the whole SC.connect authorization process begins. My browser gets redirected to

```
https://soundcloud.com/connect?state=SoundCloud_Dialog_c3241&client_id=########‌​############################&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Fcallbac‌​k.html&response_type=code_and_token&scope=non-expiring&display=popup
```

I then press connect to authorize access and then the browser redirects to the `callback.html` located at `http://localhost:9000/callback.html` but with a code, state and access token attached to it like so

```
http://localhost:9000/callback.html?code=508aa0dd5ce3d0f4254157a487fc4826&st‌​ate=SoundCloud_Dialog_c3241#access_token=1-46482-7907892-1328d9e0fc383baf&scope=n‌​on-expiring
```

Once that page loads I see an error in the Dev Tools console show up

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SC' of null
```

Is that normal?

Also, I don't want the app to be redirected back to the `callback.html` at `http://localhost:9000/callback.html` since my app is based around my `index.html`, or the `http://localhost:9000/#/` URL. **How do I make it go back to** `http://localhost:9000/#/`**?**

I started thinking maybe it's because it does not have access to the SoundCloud SDK so I put in

```
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
```

in the `<head>` of `callback.html` but the error persists.

### UPDATE 3 : UPDATE 2 Issue Solved

So I tried it in Firefox and it worked fine. A pop up actually popped up asking me to sign in/connect. After doing so my callback.html was called in the pop up window and then it disappeared all as expected. My main app window remained but with user authentication. The reason it was not working in Chrome was because the pop up was being blocked silently the whole time so Chrome would actually leave my app, go to the sign in/connect page, after I press connect it would go to `callback.html`. I guess because it was a window tab it would disappear like the code instructed it to. Sorry for my bad explanation. Still a beginner to JS and SC API.

Comment: what have you set as the redirect_uri in your app’s settings?

Comment: I have tried different combinations of urls for the `redirect_uri` and my app's `redirect_uri` at my Soundcloud app settings page. I expand on the 3 different combos in my post above.

Comment: There's a syntax error, you forget to add a comma after client_id's value

Comment: Ok that got rid of the syntax error. Thanks.

Comment: how did you solved your update 2? Does it worked because you added <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script> in callback.html file on your server?

Comment: @V_PULL read update 3. I explain that it was because Chrome was not allowing pop-ups. Here is how to enable pop-ups for certain URLs https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472?hl=en Hope that helps

Comment: @s3z i tried the same code in Firefox; it called the callback.html in my pop up window but after that its not getting closed. Its showing  "This popup should automatically close in a few seconds". But that pop up window is not getting closed.

Comment: Are you actually capturing the token? After the user gives permission to authenticate your app, the user is redirected to your callback page, along with the token and code, but it then closes. Assuming you are going to capture it here, how would you associate the code + token with an actual SoundCloud user? I suppose you could use the session or a cookie, but that seems dirty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the callback URI, they definitely need to match the app settings page. Most probably using the `#` in the URI won't work, but all that `redirect_uri` file needs to have is a call to `window.opener.SC.connectCallback`, so it doesn't need to be part of your JS app structure.

Comment: Ok I figured out how to serve up `callback.html` so Authentication works but I am getting an error which I outline in UPDATE 2 in my original post above. Any ideas?